# Running containers over an Ubuntu container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I need to separate the environments so my team could work without ports conflicts. My idea was to use an ubuntu container to run a lot of other containers and map just the ports we would use, without conflict.

Unfortunately after the Docker installation over the ubuntu container it gives the following error:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is
>   the docker daemon running?

Is it possible to use Docker over containers? Does this idea works?

Plus, if this is not the best way to solve the original problem could you please give me a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First question:

I think you have to bind the docker daemon to your Ubuntu container

`-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Or optional using the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) with the **DinD** flag (docker in docker) which based on Ubuntu 18.09

`docker run --privileged --name some-docker -v /my/own/var-lib-docker:/var/lib/docker -d docker:dind`

---

#### Second question:

Instead of the ubuntu container with docker you could use a `reverse proxy` in front of your other service containers.

For example [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/) or [nginx](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The volume solution worked BUT now the containers are linked with host's containers, which would invalidate the solution purpose. Any comment about this? Also, thank you for the reverse proxy solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use kubernetes, create multiple namespaces for each developer. Use nginx and dynamic server_name to map url to different namespaces.